# Concatenate two tensorflow datasets into one dataset element as shown in the example

Tags: tensorflow, merge, dataset

**Example**
I have following two datasets,
first dataset element is:

```
tf.Tensor([ 1.     72.      0.      5.6431 28.199 ], shape=(5,), dtype=float64)
```

Second dataset element is:

```
tf.Tensor(
[6.6200e-03 3.3800e-05 4.0100e-03 3.1700e-03 1.2040e-02 2.5650e-02
 2.3000e-01 1.4380e-02 1.3090e-02 1.6620e-02 4.3140e-02 1.4290e-02
 2.1640e+01 4.1888e-01 5.4842e-01 1.6006e-01], shape=(16,), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(34.398, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

I would like to get a dataset having dataset element as below:

```
tf.Tensor(
[1.     72.      0.      5.6431 28.199, 6.6200e-03 3.3800e-05 4.0100e-03 3.1700e-03 1.2040e-02 2.5650e-02
 2.3000e-01 1.4380e-02 1.3090e-02 1.6620e-02 4.3140e-02 1.4290e-02
 2.1640e+01 4.1888e-01 5.4842e-01 1.6006e-01], shape=(21,), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(34.398, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

How do I do it?
Thank you very much for your help

The following code generates an error:

```
for featb, feate,label in packed_ds.take(1):
     print("featb: ", featb,'\n',"feate: " , feate,'\n')
     tf.concat([featb, feate], axis=1)

 featb:  tf.Tensor([ 1.     72.      0.      5.6431 28.199 ], shape=(5,), 
   dtype=float64) 
  feate:  tf.Tensor(
 [6.6200e-03 3.3800e-05 4.0100e-03 3.1700e-03 1.2040e-02 2.5650e-02
 2.3000e-01 1.4380e-02 1.3090e-02 1.6620e-02 4.3140e-02 1.4290e-02
 2.1640e+01 4.1888e-01 5.4842e-01 1.6006e-01], shape=(16,), dtype=float64) 

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call 
  last)
  <ipython-input-16-3cb13cecc2c2> in <module>()
  1 for featb, feate,label in packed_ds.take(1):
  2   print("featb: ", featb,'\n',"feate: " , feate,'\n')
  ----> 3 tf.concat([featb, feate], axis=1)

  4 frames
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, 
   from_value)

   InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Expected concatenating dimensions in 
   the range [-1, 1), but got 1 [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

   As I could not add my error as comment, I have edited the question
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `tf.concat` function, which is available for more details at this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat.

In addition, pay attention to the concatenation axis, which is 0 in your case, otherwise you cannot concatenate.

e.g. `resulting_tensor = tf.concat([tensor1,tensor2],axis=0)`

As an additional explanation why the axis is 0, is that `(5,)` and `(16,)` are equivalent to `(5,1)`,`(16,1)`, and since the `axis = 1` (second axis) in both tensors is the same, we concantenate on the 0 axis, which leads to `(5+16,) = (21,)` final tensor dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have edited the question to show the error generated ...

Comment: The parameter axis should be 0, as I updated my answer. Your code should work now.

Comment: If it worked, please accept my answer as the solving one.

Comment: It is the custom on StackOverflow when someone answers and solves your problem, you either upvote or accept(if the answer provided is the best out of all).